# Public Facebook Graph API Search - Avoid rate limits and user authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

We are building an application that allows the end user to do public Facebook searches using the Graph API. They find content and then put it on webpages or email.

**THE PROBLEM:**

We require the user to authenticate with THEIR username and password to avoid rate limit issues as we scale the product. This frustrates many users as they don't want to insert their credentials and adds an extra step to the user experience.

**THE QUESTION:**

Is there any way to automatically create access tokens for each user account so the end user doesn't need to add their personal Facebook credentials. Or is there a better way to do this?

I see sites like tagboard.com do the searches without authentication so it seems like it can be done. I've scoured Stack Overflow and couldn't find anything that addresses this specifically, although it could be my ignorance.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why did I get a down-vote? It was an honest question.

Comment: Probably because the question is much too broad: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Fair. Not sure how to tighten it up. I'll take it on the chin. Thanks bud,

Comment: No, you can of course not generate user access token programmatically without user interaction. And most search types require a user access token. (Search results will be specific to the user performing the search.) So either they log in, or they don’t use your service.

Comment: Perfect, I figured as much. I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something. Thanks a bunch CBroe.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically you're scraping the Facebook website? Or how do we need to imagine that the process works? And the users have to give their Facebook login credentials? If so, I think this app violates a lot of points in the Facebook Platform Policies and in the Scraping TOS.

The search for public post (i.e. also search for hashtags) has been deprecated on Aprill 30th, 2014. So, there's no way to do this via the Graph API anymore.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5#search

Also, heard of Facebook Login?

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login

Comment: Cool thanks. I wasn't going to scrape but rather use the graph API to do the public searches. If that's not supported anymore than it's all good I just wanted to ask. I'm trying to ideate for our lead DEV, he is the mastermind in the API stuff. I'm the front end guy poking in the weeds. 

To be clear we aren't scraping, we are using OAuth to create access tokens to use the API.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you're stating `We require the user to authenticate with THEIR username and password to avoid rate limit issues as we scale the product.`

Comment: Because we need to have an access token to do a public search. We can't create a universal one for all clients because we would hit rate limits so we ask the user to authenticate with their facebook to segment out the requests. I didn't know if there was a better way or something I am missing.